# DrawRect in CPLayerHostingView?

Tags: iphone

0
Hi, i am using Core-plot . but when i declare the normal UIView as CPLayerHostingView,how can i handle drawRect of that view , i cant give another custom UIview name and write code in drawRect of that view?please any help to handle drawRect of CPLayerHostingView?

Answer (score 0):

Put the CPLayerHostingView inside another UIView. The background from your custom UIView will show through if you use transparent fills in the graph.

Comment: but i want to handle touch event on CPLayerHostingView,is it possible?

Comment: It depends on what you need the touch event for. Core Plot already support touch events for scrolling the graph.

Answer (score 0):

Put the CPLayerHostingView inside another UIView. The background from your custom UIView will show through if you use transparent fills in the graph.

```
 i did this but i get on exception like this Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setHostedLayer:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5d20910'
```

Comment: Make the CPLayerHostingView a subview of the UIView. You still have to add the Core Plot graph to the CPLayerHostingView. It sounds like you tried to add it to your UIView.